# Create method for nested resource with protected ID attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, formtastic

I’m following the (now slightly outdated) [Meet Rails 3](https://peepcode.com/products/meet-rails-3-ii) tutorial from PeepCode, and am having trouble getting a couple of the tutorial’s suggestions to work together with Rails 3.2.

The tutorial has you create a `Role` model that belongs to a `Project`:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  validates :project_id, :presence => true
  attr_protected :project_id
end
```

The **routes.rb** file nests `Role` resources such that you must work with a `Role` in the context of a `Project`:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :roles
end
```

Note in the model code above, the  tutorial advises you to use `attr_protected` to protect the `:project_id` field, because it can be set “more securely” by creating every `Role` in the context of a project, like this in **roles_controller.rb**:

```
class RolesController < ApplicationController
  ⋮

  def create
    @role = project.roles.new(params[:role])
    ⋮
```

The problem is, the HTML form for creating a `Role`, which is created with [Formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic), contains a `project_id` field for selecting the project. Therefore, when `project.roles.new(params[:role])` tries to use the parameters from the form to populate the new `Role` object, it tries to set the `project_id` using mass assignment, and fails with:

> **ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in RolesController#create**
>   Can’t mass-assign protected attributes: project_id

What is the accepted way to implement this? Was protecting the `project_id` attribute a bad idea? Or is there some way to populate the new `Role` with the form data without including `project_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting `project` via `params[:project_id]` rather than `params[:role][:project_id]` you could actually be setting conflicting values anyway.

The reason Mass Assignment would want to protect this is to prevent a user entering in an arbitrary value for `project_id` that could allow a `project` that isn't under this users control. You have a couple of options.

If you had an authorative `user` or `account` attached to the object you could add in a `before_save` callback, such as `self.project_id = nil unless user.projects.find(project_id)`.

Since you don’t, I'd use the `project_id` from the hash to find the project, and fall back to the route id (I'm not sure if it would be `project_id` or just `id` off the top of my head).

```
def create
  user.
    projects.
    find(params[:role].delete(:project_id) || params[:project_id] || params[:id]).
    create(params[:role])
```

The easiest thing would be to just drop the select box from the form, since they've selected a project when choosing to create a new role – it's a nested resource.

Comment: Indeed, the very next step of the tutorial re-writes the formtastic form so that it no longer contains the project drop-down. The error, though never mentioned in the tutorial, is fixed by that change.